# How do I create and update an alist?

Tags: association-lists

This naive attempt did not work:

```
;; function_key = dict()
(setq function-key '()) 
;; function_key["evil-next-line"] = 108
(add-to-list function-key '(evil-next-line . 108))
```

It just exploded with a `(setting-constant nil)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`add-to-list`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html) accept a `symbol` as the first argument:

```
(add-to-list 'function-key '(evil-next-line . 108))
```

If your variable is lexical, you will want to use `push` instead:

```
(let ((foo ...))
  (push ... foo))
```

NB. You might want to consider [Hash Tables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html) instead of alists for lookup (they correspond to [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict) in Python).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to sds's suggestion of `add-to-list`, you can also use `push`, which doesn't require you to quote the variable:

```
(push '(evil-next-line . 108) function-key)
```

Comment: `pushnew` is also useful in order to ensure that you don't get duplicate entries in the list.